# Excel: loop through nested folders and copy paste files: object required error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through the root folder and its subfolders, and subfolders' subfolders and copy paste their files into some new location:

```
  Sub Main()
    Dim source As String
    Dim destination As String
    source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value
    destination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value

    'copy files in root folder
    Call DoFolder(source, destination)

    'loop through nested folders
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim subFolder As Variant
    subFolder = FileSystem.GetFolder(source)

    'Dim subFolder As Variant
    For Each subFolder In subFolder.SubFolders
        MsgBox (subFolder.Name)
        Debug.Print subFolder.Name

        Call DoFolder(subFolder.Name, destination)
    Next


End Sub

Sub DoFolder(source As String, destination As String)

    'copy files in root folder
    Call Copy(source, destination)

End Sub

Sub Copy(source As String, destination As String)
   Dim fileObject As String
   fileObject = Dir(source & "*.*")
   Do While fileObject <> ""
        FileCopy source & fileObject, destination & fileObject
        fileObject = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```

However I get an `object required` error in `Main` sub. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always declare variables as the expected type.  In this case it also solves your problem.  Try this code:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim subFolder As Folder
Set subFolder = fso.GetFolder(source)

For Each subFolder In subFolder.SubFolders
   MsgBox subFolder.Name
Next
```

Comment: Note that you will have to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I've figured it out - it was about the `Set` keyword - add the set, no error.